# WCF - changing function code: should I update service reference?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a WCF service that work fine, today I changed the code of one of the function in the contract I added these two lines:

```
var name = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                    select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).FirstOrDefault();
        string osFriendlyName = name != null ? name.ToString() : "Unknown";
```

that mean I added reference in the wcf server class to System.Management.
The contract hasn't change I return the same object I returned before...
Now when the client try to invoke this function I get this exception:

```
The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IEnvironmentService/GetComputerDetails' cannot be
processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be 
because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a 
binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have
the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
None).
```

What do you think the problem? Do I need to update service reference in my clients even though the contract hasn't change?

Comment: You don't ever need to update the clients service references unless you change your method signatures(return type or parameters) and/or add or remove some methods. And I don't know what your problem might be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my problem resolved I made rebuild to the solution and it is now ok!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update service reference in your clients, as [metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731823%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of service might have changed and it might throw an error.

Comment: But what metadata has changed? because I added new reference to the class?